# How can i use an instance of a class latter in the code if it is created based on if conditions earlier, in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, class, oop

I am getting error while accessing an object which i have declared based on if conditions.
(LudoPlayer is a class)
**The code is:**

```
if(n==4){
    cin>>a >>b >>c >>d;
    LudoPlayer play(a, b, c, d);
        }
if(n==3){
    cin>>a >>b >>c;
    LudoPlayer play(a, b, c);
        }
play.Dispaly();
```

**Error is:**
 error: ‘play’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us in the question, together with a description of the problems you have with it (like a copy-paste of the full and complete error output). Please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Could you add some code?

Comment: Just did that..

Comment: You might want to take a step back, and go through your books, class notes or tutorials about the concept of *scope*.

Comment: Actually i wanted to create an object with different constructors depending on some input. Like if you want to initialize two data members then with two parameter constructor and for three with three parameter constructor and so on. I could have given some default values in one maximum Parameterized constructor but just wanted to know why the other don't work. Anyway am very happy to see how supportive the community here is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other two answers will work (although, there is small error is Hazem Abaza's answer: pointer must be defined first outside the if block).
You often can't use the option from adrisui3's answer though, depending on how the constructor is defined.

Another option is to make a function that returns a LudoPlayer
(This can be a free function, or probably better, a static member)

```
LudoPlayer makeLudoPlayer(int n) {
  if (n == 4) {
    int a, b, c, d;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    return LudoPlayer(a, b, c, d);
  }
  else {
    int a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    return LudoPlayer(a, b, c);
  }
}

//Then, main may look like this:
int main() {
  int n = 3; // or 4
  LudoPlayer play = makeLudoPlayer(n);
  play.Display();
}
```

Comment: Just in passing, at the moment there are no answers "above" this one. Answers get rearranged.

Comment: So I'll go on picking on you. <g> If someone adds an answer there will be three other answers, and "[t]he other two answers" will be confusing. This is a good place for deliberate vagueness. To be clear: good answer! +1.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common enough issue to warrant a much more thorough solution. Note that in all this code I've simplified the initialization by removing the reading of the variables, in order to keep the code small. Pretend that that's all there.

One approach is to use a setter function:

```
LudoPlayer play;
if (n == 3) {
    play.set(1, 2, 3);
} else if (n == 4) {
    play.set(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

That works, but it requires that `LudoPlayer` have a `set` function corresponding to every set of constructor arguments. So another approach is to simply use the constructor:

```
LudoPlayer play;
if (n == 3) {
    play = LudoPlayer(1, 2, 3);
} else if (n == 4) {
    play = LudoPlayer(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Those two approaches are known as "two-phase construction", and that's usually a derogatory term. A constructor should put an object into a usable state, and you shouldn't have to immediately go back and rewrite that state.

Further, for some types it doesn't make sense to **have** a default constructor; every object needs to be constructed with some external parameter in order to be meaningful. Adding an otherwise meaningless default constructor in order to support this kind of initialization is inside out design.

Instead, you can do the appropriate initialization when the object is created:

```
LudoPlayer play = (n == 3) ? LudoPlayer(1, 2, 3) : LudoPlayer(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Yes, I cheated: you can't do that when you have to prompt for initializers, like the original code did. But that leads to another approach: write a factory function.

```
LudoPlayer build(int n) {
    if (n == 3) {
        return LudoPlayer(1, 2, 3);
    } else if (n == 4) {
        return LudoPlayer(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

when you create the object just call the factory function:

```
LudoPlayer play(build(n));
```

And, yes, this requires that the type being constructed has a move constructor. If you traffic in non-copyable and non-movable types you've got a host of problems beyond anything involved here.

As for that factory function, for something this simple it's fine. But if there's more going on, it's easy to get lost. I often find that I'm editing the wrong place in that `if ... else if ...` ladder. So write separate functions:

```
LudoPlayer build3() {
    return LudoPlayer(1, 2, 3);
}

LudoPlayer build4() {
    return LudoPlayer(1, 2, 3, 4);
}

LudoPlayer build(int n) {
    if (n == 3) {
        return build3();
    } else if (n == 4) {
        return build4();
    }
}
```

Or write that dispatcher with a switch statement:

```
LudoPlayer build(int n) {
    switch(n) {
    case 3: return build3();
    case 4: return build4();
    }
}
```

In this case, your compiler might complain that there's no `default` statement. Whether there should be one depends on context. If the value of `n` hasn't been validated, add a `default` that handles the error appropriately. If it has already been validated, don't add a redundant `default`. You know your code better than the compiler does; turn off stupid warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I've had that problem many times. It's quite annoying, I know. The best way to solve it, as far as I know, is the following:

```
LudoPlayer play;

if(n==4)
{
    cin>>a >>b >>c >>d;
    play.setValues(a, b, c, d);
}

if(n==3)
{
    cin>>a >>b >>c;
    play.setValues(a,b,c)
}

play.Dispaly();
```

Be aware that you'd need to use default parameters in LudoPlayer::setValues(), and also create a constructor without parameters in which you'd give a default value to every data member.

Hope it was helpful. If you need any extra help, just let me know!

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to benroberts 99's answer, but uses an IIFE https://www.bfilipek.com/2016/11/iife-for-complex-initialization.html so the complex construction can be done inline

```
int main() {
  int n = 3; // or 4

  LudoPlayer play = [](int n) {
      if (n == 4) {
        int a, b, c, d;
        std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
        return LudoPlayer{a, b, c, d};
      }
      else {
        int a, b, c;
        std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
        return LudoPlayer{a, b, c};
      }
    }(n);  // pass the argument in

  play.Display();
}
```